# ReactJS - Render Redirect with data from Firebase - "Nothing was returned from render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching an URL from a collection in Firebase linked to an alias field. This part of code is OK, but I can't manage to make a Redirect with the URL field of retrieved data. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FirebaseContext } from '../firebase'

function RedirUrl () {
  const { alias } = useParams()
  let link = ''
  const { firebase } = React.useContext(FirebaseContext)
  const dbRef = firebase.db.collection('links')

  function getRedir () {
    dbRef.where('alias', '==', alias).get().then(snapshot => {
      link = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        return { ...doc.data() }
      })
      console.log(link[0].longUrl) // it is okay
      return link[0].longUrl
    })
  }
  return <Redirect to={getRedir()} />
}

export default RedirUrl
```

And here the warning message:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in
> `Redirect`, but its value is `undefined`

I guess the page is rendering before the retrieved data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably because the request hasn't finished before the render is complete. You might need to do something like: 
`const redirectUrl = getRedit();
if (!redirectUrl) return <></>;
return <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />`

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Redirect to={getRedir()} />
```

Here you are passing a promise to the `to` prop, but it should receive a string.
You can use `useEffect` for getting the data from firebase:

```js
const { alias } = useParams();
const { link, setLink } = useState('');
const { firebase } = React.useContext(FirebaseContext);
const dbRef = firebase.db.collection('links');

useEffect(() => {
    dbRef
        .where('alias', '==', alias)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            const links = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                return { ...doc.data() };
            });
            console.log(links[0].longUrl); // it is okay
            setLink(links[0].longUrl);
        });
}, []);
return link ? <Redirect to={link} /> : <></>;
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Is there a way to make that Redirect go to an external website? I got the following result: https://mydomain/https://externaldomain

Managed going on window.location.href inside useEffect.